# Jupyter is stuck

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have this following code:

[image: Code]

The code is simply stuck when I give input n=6 ,(in jupyter)I don't know what to do please help.

```
n=int(input("Enter a number to experiment:"))
l=[]
w=[]
nw=[]
c=0
for i in range(2*n):
 if(i<n):
   l.append(0)
 else:
   l.append(1)

import itertools as it
permset=set([i for i in it.permutations(l)])
for x in permset:
  w.append(x)
print (w)
for j in range(len(w)):
  c=1

   for y in range(2*n-1):

      if(w[j][y]==w[j][y+1]):
         c=c
      else:
         c=c+1

nw.append(c)
print(nw)
from collections import Counter
Counter(nw)
```

Comment: What is your end goal?

Comment: I want to run this for various n and understand how the frequencies of the 1,2, etc in nw depend on n

Comment: This code is written to solve a problem in combinatorics...

Comment: "The phenomenon of just a few inputs producing a large number of outcomes is called a combinatorial explosion and is something to keep in mind when working with combinations(), combinations_with_replacement(), and permutations()" [source](https://realpython.com/python-itertools/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the call to `itertools.permutations`. It is computing every possible ordering of the array built previously, which for N=6 is:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I believe this will return (12!)=479001600 items, which your code is then turning into a set to remove duplicates. It never gets that far of course, but if it did, I believe the 479001600 items would be turned into a set of just 924 items.

Not sure what your goal is but maybe what you need for this part is a way to generate that set of 924 items without building the larger list, which has many many duplicates. As I understand it, that part of the code is building the set of arrays of size (2*n) where exactly half of the elements are 0 and half are 1.

Comment: Yes I see... Thank you I will try to find  easier way out